# Firebase functions deploy: The service has encountered an error during container import

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We're trying to deploy firebase functions and we continuously have this error: `The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again late`

Here's a video overview: https://www.loom.com/share/9afb2facb5e3461ebef74e7e802a2761

```json
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 14,
      "message": "The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again later"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {},
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/voypost-matching-prod/locations/europe-west3/functions/createFromJobPubSub"
  },
  "insertId": "-wq3kwnb2c",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "voypost-matching-prod",
      "function_name": "createFromJobPubSub",
      "region": "europe-west3"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-01-07T16:39:01.688761Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/voypost-matching-prod/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/dm95cG9zdC1tYXRjaGluZy1wcm9kL2V1cm9wZS13ZXN0My9jcmVhdGVGcm9tSm9iUHViU3ViL0pOaGkxYW9zMWxj",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-01-07T16:39:02.021123649Z"
}
```

As per [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-import), it may be due to non-utf8 characters, but there are none (checked using https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741313 `grep -axv '.*' ./lib/**/*.js`)

It failed 3 times in a row and continues failing. And every time it fails on the same functions.

There is always only one deployment ongoing - we don't run multiple `firebase functions deploy` at the same time.

The original discussion is [on their github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4266#issuecomment-1374538269), but we were refered here.

Comment: As it is suggested in github raise [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/getting-support) as it requires internal logs for analyzing, which can only be accessible by engineering team

Comment: As I also mentioned on Github, it requires a premium support plan. So here I'm trying to look for workarounds already known by the community to fix this w/o spending money on fixing what is expected to work.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me on projects with many cloud functions.

As a workaround I run a deploy command for that specific function, instead of the whole functions project.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myFunctionName
```